# Why does this Fourier transform not match the formula?

Tags: functions, fourier-analysis

From [this](https://www.thefouriertransform.com/pairs/sinusoids.php) page:

[image]
[image]

So I'm trying to get that result in Mathematica. From the fourier formula above, we can see that {a, b} = {1,-1}.

[image]

However, the code below returns a different result.

```
FourierTransform[Cos[2 \[Pi] A t], t, w, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]
(*\[Pi] DiracDelta[2 A \[Pi] - w] + \[Pi] DiracDelta[2 A \[Pi] + w]*)
```

Is there anything wrong here?

Comment: The result is true, its linked pseudo-proof is not: that improper integral diverges. The Fourier transforms of distributions are  not defined as improper integrals (see  "Tempered distributions" section in [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform)). I  am sure those Fourier transforms are implemented as table values in Mathematica.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the confusion is between frequency in cycles per second or Hz and frequency in radians per second. In the page you link to the frequency is in Hz. Thus to match this convention the FourierParameters have to be {0, -2 [Pi]} Try this

```
FourierTransform[Cos[2 \[Pi] A t], t, f, 
 FourierParameters -> {0, -2 \[Pi]}]

(* 1/2 DiracDelta[A - f] + 1/2 DiracDelta[A + f] *)
```

Hope that helps